# Improving MySQL query performance - possible index problems

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I've seen many questions like mine, but after reading them all I got rather confused.

To sum up - I've got a query that select products from a table and adds more information about them from other tables.

Query:

```
SELECT 
      p.product_id, 
      p.product_name, 
      p.product_seo_url, 
      p.product_second_name, 
      p.product_intro_plain, 
      p.product_price,
      p.product_price_promo, 
      p.product_promo_expire_date, 
      p.product_views,
      p.product_code, 
      p.product_exquisite, 
      p.product_rating, 
      p.product_votes,
      p.product_date_added, 
      p.product_returned, 
      p.product_price_returned,
      ( SELECT gal.image_filelocation 
           FROM 3w_products_gallery gal 
           WHERE gal.product_id = p.product_id 
           ORDER BY show_order ASC 
           LIMIT 1 )  image_filelocation, 
      m.man_image_location, 
      m.man_name, 
      m.man_seo_url 
   FROM 
      3w_products p 
         LEFT JOIN 3w_manufacturers m 
            ON p.man_id = m.man_id
         LEFT JOIN 3w_products_cat_rel pcr 
            ON p.product_id  = pcr.product_id
   WHERE 
          pcr.ctg_id = '19'
      AND p.man_id = '190'
   ORDER BY 
      p.product_id DESC 
   LIMIT 
      0, 24
```

The strange things that happen are that the query sometimes executes for 0.001 sec. and sometimes for 30+ seconds.

There is what EXPLAIN shows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNtBX.png

I assume the problem lies in the indexes of the tables. Can you tell me how to setup them?

Let me know if you need any more information about the tables or whatever!

Best,
Dimitar

Comment: You know that "WHERE (pcr.ctg_id = '19')" makes the pcr outer join to perform as an inner join? (Move condition to the left join's ON clause if you really want a left join.)

Comment: You missed a comma near `ASC LIMIT 1) 
image_filelocation,` After the query inside the bracket ends, you should have a comma

Comment: There should be "as" between those two.

Comment: How many rows the query is expected to return, if run without last `LIMIT`? Here, the instruction `ORDER BY DESC LIMIT` could be evaluated only after the whole stuff is done. I guess that some ctg_id/man_id sections are quite large.

Comment: @user4419802 - Around 1000 results.

Comment: What indexes do you have already?  We need to see your current table and index definitions if we are to help you out.  Also, http://use-the-index-luke.com is a great tutorial about indexes.

Comment: @Gunaseelan: No comma is missing; Dimitar: AS is optional syntax.  Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table.

Comment: 0.001 sec smells like it was found in the Query Cache.  That timing is bogus.  30 seconds for a 3-way JOIN with ~1000 rows sounds like something else was going on -- perhaps INSERTs or other stuff on these tables?

Answer (score 0):

IF your "ID" columns are actually numeric, remove the quotes around them implying strings... even though it would to an implied conversion.  If numeric, keep it numeric.

As stated by another in the comments, your LEFT JOIN via the "pcr" alias with its criteria in the WHERE clause turns this into an inner join.

```
 FROM 
      3w_products p 
         LEFT JOIN 3w_manufacturers m 
            ON p.man_id = m.man_id
         LEFT JOIN 3w_products_cat_rel pcr 
            ON p.product_id  = pcr.product_id
            AND pcr.ctg_id = 19
   WHERE 
      AND p.man_id = 190
```

Field-level queries can kill performance since the select for each field (your image location) is done once for every record.  To at least help this performance, table 3w_products_gallery should have an index ON ( product_id, show_order )

Your main 3w_products table should have an index on (man_id, product_id )... The Man_ID to optimize the WHERE clause by manufacturer, but also the product ID to help optimize the ORDER BY criteria.

Your 3w_manufacturers table, I would suspect already has a valid index on (man_id), since it appears to be the primary key to the table.

Additionally, being web-based content, you might be better to DE-NORMALIZE your product table by adding one new column for "GalleryShowOrder".  Then, add a trigger to your Gallery table that any insert or update will then push the first "showOrder" value back to the product table.  This way, when you query, you can just add another join to that table on the product and KNOWN show order.  If your gallery is returning 1000's of records, even though you are only limiting to 24, it still needs to get all record before the order by is applied. Thus 1000's of subqueries for each of the gallery images.

and your field selection would just become

```
gal.image_filelocation,
```

and your JOIN would add the following

```
  LEFT JOIN 3w_products_gallery gal 
     on p.product_id = gal.product_id
    AND p.GalleryShowOrder = gal.show_order
```

Comment: 'table 3w_products_gallery should have an index ON ( product_id, show_order )' - well, it is useful only if there is a bunch of images for a given id. Otherwise, plain `index ON (product_id)` is sufficient.

Comment: 'main 3w_products table should have an index on (man_id, product_id )' - again, if TS states that the query returns no more than 1000 rows, it's no use to optimize `ORDER BY` by using composite index. Consider also, that MySQL would be probably unable to optimize `ORDER BY DESC` as it requires `index ON (man_id, product_id DESC)` which is not supported (see http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/order-by-asc-desc-nulls-last)